# Dojo and javascript: lightweight tooltip in onclick on anchor tab

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, tooltip, alert

I have a dojo datagrid and I am using a formatter that puts, among other things, link in the cell.

The formatter looks like this:

```
var descshort = value[1].substring(0,220);

return '<a href="'+ value[2] +'">'+value[0]+'</a><br /><div class="gridItemDescription">'+descshort+'&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="showDesc();return false;">show more...</a></div>';
```

So you see I am only displaying the first 220 characters of value[1].

What I want to do now is show a dialog or tool tip when you click on the "show more..." link that has the complete value[1] (right now there is a showDesc(); function that does nothing). So far I got it to show up in a javascript alert by using:

```
onclick="javascript:alert(\' ' + value[1] + ' \');return false;"
```

instead of a function, but I don't like the way the alert looks, especially in IE. If I try to use a function, I can't seem to but it in a place where it will grab the value[1] data. Is there anything in Dojo or javascript I can use in the onclick event on the link to show the contents of value[1]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to call a function for a dojo dialog and pass the values as arguments to the dojo dialog! Also it took me a while to realize that in the formatter I need to use \ to escape some of the ' characters that are used to build the returned string while inserting values as arguments.

```
elliotDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
  title: "My Dialog",
  content: "test content",
  style: "width: 450px"
});

showDesc = function(layer, layer2){
 // set the content of the dialog:
elliotDialog.set("title", layer2);
 elliotDialog.set("content", layer);
 elliotDialog.show();
};
```

The onclick in the formatter looks like this:

```
onclick="showDesc(\'' + value[1] + '\',\'' + value[0] + '\');return false;"
```