# Open a Popup or tooltip onclick of link in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am following Tutorials everywhere around the web to figure out this as i am new to dojo, i know jquery but Dojo, no way

I am following links from stackoverflow itself but unable tofigure out the code:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476084/dojo-and-javascript-lightweight-tooltip-in-onclick-on-anchor-tab
```

I tried wring some code but it is saying as

***showDialog is undefined..***

Also, What is requirement is:

1. Click on the link to open the dialog or tooltip just after the link, positionsing near it.
2. Having a link inside the popup or tooltip of Close it, so it should actually close the toltip or popup,

Here is my try till now:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script>
dojo.require("dijit.Dialog");
        dojo.addOnLoad(showDialog);
        elliotDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
          title: "My Dialog",
          content: "test content",
          style: "width: 450px"
        });
        showDialog = function(){
            // set the content of the dialog:
            elliotDialog.set("title");
            elliotDialog.set("content");
            elliotDialog.show();
        };
</script>   

<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showDialog();" class="moreLink">More pricing...</a></p>
        <div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="elliotDialog" title="More Pricing Option">

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in your code:

You declared both a declarative styled widget and a programmatically created widget with the same name. Remove the following part of your code:

```html
<div dojoType="dijit.Dialog" id="elliotDialog" title="More Pricing Option">

</div>
```

---

You're using `dojo.addOnLoad()` wrong. The `dojo.addOnLoad()` function should be called when you want to wait for the modules and the DOM to load. There's no reason to call the `showDialog()` function in here.
Even worse, at the moment you're calling it, the `showDialog()` function does not even exist since you declare it later in your code. This is the reason why you got the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: showDialog is not defined
```

What should happen is that you wrap your dialog creation code and everything that depends on it, inside the `dojo.addOnLoad()` function, for example:

```js
dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
    elliotDialog = new dijit.Dialog({
        title: "My Dialog",
        content: "test content",
        style: "width: 450px"
    });
    showDialog = function(){
        // set the content of the dialog:
        console.log(elliotDialog);
        elliotDialog.set("title");
        elliotDialog.set("content");
        elliotDialog.show();
    };
});
```

---

You're using the setters of the dialog incorrectly. When using the `dijit/Dialog::set()` function, you should provide two parameters, one to define the property you want to set, and second the value you want to use, so in this case the title and content you would like to display.

For example:

```js
elliotDialog.set("title", "My title");
elliotDialog.set("content", "My content");
```

If you did all that, your code should work just fine, as you can see in the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4jnHk/